# What is the necessary of doing DFS in decreasing order of finishing times in Kosaraju algorithm for finding Strongly connected components?

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am learning Kosaraju algorithm for finding strongly connected components from here [Kosaraju algorithm](http://www.columbia.edu/~cs2035/courses/csor4231.F11/scc.pdf) .
But I can't understand what is the necessity of doing dfs(G^T) in decreasing order of finishing times i.e mentioned in Point 3 in above link.

Comment: Feel free for any queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a simple graph with two vertices A and B and one edge from B to A (or A to B in G^T).  If you do dfs(G^T) on the vertices in order A then B then you output this as a single strongly connected component.  Whereas it should be two separate components.

Informally, the necessity of doing the vertices in the specified order is to ensure you only go "up" G^T links when you can also go "down" G links first.

Answer (score 1):

Say your original graph is this:

[image]

**C1,C2,C3 and C4** are strongly connected components of the graph and can contain any number of vertices.

**If our aim is to find the Strongly connected components of the graph,the best thing to do is start the DFS FROM ANY VERTEX OF C4 AND MARK THEM VISITED**.

**Reason**:Because **C4** is a SCC and there is no outgoing edge from C4,**initiating DFS from any vertex of C4 will only visit vertices of C4 as there is no outgoing vertices**.

So we get our first **SCC**.

Next step **would be either start DFS from a vertex of C2 or C3 because,C2(OR c3) is SCC,it would visit all vertices of C2(OR c3) and the only outgoing edge is to C4 WHOSE VERTICES ARE ALREADY MARKED VISITED AND THEREFORE WOULD NOT BE INCLUDED IN SCC**.

So we get our second **SCC**.

Next step would be to start DFS from C2(if previously C3),otherwise C3(if previously C2). and it would end up visiting vertices of only that **SCC** and the reason is already mentioned above.

Lastly, we would start DFS from a vertex of C1 and it would end of visiting vertices of only that **SCC(C1)** and the reason is already mentioned above.

**NOW I WILL ANSWER YOUR QUESTION**

The order **C4,C3,C2,C1** or **C4,C2,C3,C1**, is basically obtained as the order of **vertices in decreasing finishing times for the following graph(Reversed of the original)**

[image]

That is if we initiate DFS from any vertex of above graph, then list of vertices that we obtain in order of decreasing finishing times would have **the vertices of C4 first,then vertices of C2,then vertices of C3 and lastly vertices of C1 OR the vertices of C4 first,then vertices of C3,then vertices of C2 and lastly vertices of C1.**

**If we do not initiate DFS in decreasing order of finishing times, say we initiate DFS from any vertex of C1(that is in the second DFS, of original graph),what that DFS would do,it would list all the vertices of graph  AS ONE SCC,AS FIRST DIAGRAM CLEARLY INDICATES THAT,because there is outgoing edges from C1 to C2,C3 and from there we can reach C4 as:**

**vertices of C2,C3,C4 are marked unvisited**

**Or say if we initiate DFS from any vertex of C2 before initiating DFS from any vertex of C4, what it would do is list the vertices of C2 and C4 as one SCC,because C4 vertices are marked unvisited.**.

**So the main reason behind initiating second dfs in decreasing order of finishing times is so that vertices of only that SCC are listed in a dfs and marked visited.**

Answer (score 0):

Take a graph that is just a path.

```
5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1
```

If we didn't DFS the transpose in decreasing order of finishing times, then we could start at, e.g., 4, and report {4, 5} as a component.